# Can Entity Framework(Database-First Model) ignore unused columns being deleted or renamed?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

***Backgroud:***
EDMX was built pretty straight forward, I just selected all tables and clicked "Ok" button several times, the thing is, not all the columns are/will be consumed by system.

***What happened***
Later on, several nice-to-have columns became "kiss-good-bye" columns, and bam, several components stopped functioning as exceptions are thrown from entity framework saying "Invalid Column Name xxxxx"

***What is wanted to be achieved***
Hopefully the legendary gurus in stackoverflow will kindly shine light on "how to let EF ignore unused columns, even if they are no more in DB".

System design sometimes would like some room. so there go all the candidate columns that might not be in use after a while, yet DB-First approach takes in all the candidates, it's possible for MS to come up with some kind of a policy to ignore unused properties, and the complexity and cost to implement this mechanism seems not very high.

In Following there lays a few things I tried but didn't have any luck, maybe it's the way I tried it, or it's just not the thing to turn things around.

***Method #1 tried on my side***

Implementing data loading in a more column-specific way, Table1.Select(Column1, 2, 3, 4);
Why I dropped it: it's just too much for me to rewrite so I didn't even verify whether it solves the problem.

***Method #2 tried on my side***

Why I dropped it: it just doesn't work

***Method #3***

DefaultValue=""

Why I dropped it: it just doesn't work, still got "invalid column name" exception

***#4***

Database.SetInitialize

Why I dropped it: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of research, now I have some workaround, but I haven't got any solution to this.

1. Inject Data Contract into EDMX calls so that EF will only retrieve the columns required by upper layers.
   Pros: this is hopefully one-shot-two-birds straight forward, using the mapper between Data Contract and EDMX Schema to make EF calls.
   Cons: Perf is a concern, hopefully latest version reflection won't be taking up too much CPU Span, and also implementation will have to be a lot to cover all EF calls.
2. Set up a Unit Test case,

   **Steps** Retrieve currently-used EDMX from DLL Resource Section, Retrieve latest EDMX from DB, if actual doesn't match expected, alert EDMX owner in the Dev Team.

   **Expected Result** on-the-fly exported EDMX

   **Actual Result** existing EDMX exported from DLL Resource Section

Wish this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your database schema changes, you need to update the EDMX model in the Designer.  Right click in the white space and click "Update Model from Database...".  This needs to be done every time your schema changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I was thinking a more idiot-proof way, that some how MS can let model-loading be aware of all the referenced properties, and ignore the unused properties.

Comment: Maybe what we need here is something similar to Dependency Injection, but I hope it's not...

Comment: Dependency Injection won't solve this issue.  DI is very useful in MVC applications when implemented properly but it does not affect the edmx model.  It does however abstract your business layer so you can call all of your repo methods per service.  MS won't come up with a way to ignore columns.  I'm not really sure why you would want to do this anyways?  What is the problem you are trying to solve by hiding columns?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The reason I am so obsessed with this is because our DB Team has difficulty in notifying Web Team every time there's a change in DB Schema, so the only way right now to find it out is to find a crash bug and then web team gets to realize it's high time for a refresh in EDMX.

Comment: Ah, I see.  To me this is a process issue.  The DB team should be making these changes on DEV only.  Your team should have scheduled roll-outs to PROD, that way code and db schema stay in sync.  Whether you're using EF or a simple DAO with stored procedures, you will run into this issue constantly if both teams do not work together.  If this is a DEV environment issue, it's good practice to update your edmx anyways - or even wipe it and re-build it.  To avoid this issue, we develop locally and hand the DBA our db changes.

Comment: You know what, now we are actually doing some POC using Dependency Injection Methodology, stay tuned and I will be debriefing when there's some progress, btw, another idea just came out last night, we can come up with a DB Schema Monitor, you know, sending out alerts whenever there's a change in columns, maybe a DB trigger, or a C# Console playing with SMO, if you have some detailed design, post it and we can call it an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't really answer the original issue - which is the EDMX needs to be updated each time the schema changes.  Yes, you can write an app to do a compare for you, but it will probably trigger a lot during development :)